# A counting question: general pattern?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $m < n$ be two positive integers. Let $X$ denote the integers $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

Let $A$ be a fixed $m$-subset of $X$.
I am trying to figure out an explicit characterization of
$$
N(A) = \#\{B \subset X : |B| = m, \max(A \cap B^c) < \max(B \cap A^c) \}. 
$$
We define $\max(\emptyset) = 0$.

For instance if $m = 2, n = 3$, then by case work, we see
$$
N(\{1, 2\}) = 2,
\quad 
N(\{1, 3\}) = 1,
\quad \mbox{and} \quad 
N(\{2, 3\}) = 0.  
$$

I don't see the general pattern though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's parametrize the the space of solutions by setting $x = \max(B \backslash A)$ assuming that $x > \max(A \backslash B).$

Now consider any $y > x$. If $y \in A$ then we must have $y \in B$; otherwise, we'll have $\max(A \backslash B) \geq y > x$, a contradiction. So, $$\{y \in A | y > x\} \subseteq B \cap \{x+1, x+2, \ldots, n\}.$$

Similarly if $y>x$ and $y \in B$ then we must have $y \in A$: if not, then $y \in B \backslash A$ with $y > x = \max(B \backslash A)$ again a contradiction. So, $$B \cap \{x+1, x+2, \ldots, n\} \subseteq \{y \in A | y > x\}.$$

So, we conclude that $$B \cap \{x+1, x+2, \ldots, n\} = \{y \in A | y > x\}.$$ In other words, the elements of $B$ beyond $x$ are determined and must be exactly $\{y \in A | y > x\}$. Then every such $B$ can be written as $B' \cup \{x\} \cup \{y \in A | y > x\}$ where $B'$ is an arbitrary subset of $\{1,2, \ldots, x-1\}$ of size $m-1-|\{y \in A | y > x\}|$. Finally, no such $x$ can be in $A$. Thus we conclude

$$N(A) = \sum_{x \in X \backslash A} {x-1 \choose m-1 -f(A,x)}$$

where $f(A,x) = |\{y \in A: y > x\}|$.

Comment: I am just curious. If $A$ is a uniformly at random chosen $m$-subset, what can you say about $N(A)$? Or at least what is its typical size? I don't really understand this quantity very well. I can put this in a new question if you prefer.

Comment: Well, if $A$ and $B$ are chosen randomly we'll have a 50% chance of $\max(A \cap B^c) < \max(B \cap A^c)$. So I'd expect $N(A) \approx {n \choose m}/2$ on average.

Comment: By this logic, is it also true that $N(A)$ is uniform on $\{1, \dots, K\}$, $K = \binom{n}{m}$?

Comment: I did a quick simulation and yes it appears to be roughly uniform.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did this problem arise?

Comment: I was trying to construct a counterexample to a problem, and in order to quantify the size of a particular gap, I needed to know what $N(A)$ looks like for nearly random $A$. I was hoping the formula would be a little more insightful, but I understand the decomposition around the pivot (largest element) x.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I realize that the distribution of $N(A)$ is exactly uniform.  You can sort the subsets by an ordering $<$ where $A<B$ means that $\max(A\backslash B) < \max(B \backslash A)$ and this turns out to be a **total** ordering.  So if you list off the sets in this order, $N(A)$ just gives you all of the ones that occur later in this list, and it follows that $N(A)$ is uniform between $0$ and ${n \choose m} -1$.

Comment: For example, for $n = 4$ and $m = 2$ we have a list $\{1, 2\},\{1, 3\},\{2, 3\},\{1, 4\},\{2, 4\},\{3, 4\}$. Then if $A = \{1,4\}$ we know you can compute $N(A) = 2$ because there are two sets $B$ further in the list, namely $\{2, 4\},\{3, 4\}$, both having $\max(A\backslash B) < \max (B \backslash A)$.

Comment: How do you show that $<$ is transitive? i.e., $\max(A \setminus C) < \max(C \setminus A)$ when $A < B, B < C$?

Comment: Suppose that $A<B$ and $B<C$. First note that we can assume, without generality, that there is no $x \in A \cap B \cap C$, because if there is, it makes no difference as it doesn't appear in any of the sets $A \backslash B$, $C \backslash A$, and so on. So we assume $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$.

Comment: Now let $x = \max A \cup B \cup C$. If $x \in A$, then $\max A \backslash B < \max B \backslash A$ would give a contradiction unless $x \in B$. Similarly, $x \in B$ implies $x \in C$. So we have $x \in A \implies  x \in B \implies x \in C$.  But not all of these can be true at the same time, by the assumption $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$.  So we must have $x \in C \backslash A$, and then it's clear that $x = \max(C \backslash A) > \max(A \backslash C)$.